# IFrames make my page scrolls To The Bottom Of The Page

Tags: html, iframe

these are the `iframes` and weirdly when I inspect them I see the whole page HTML inside them. is that normal??!!. when they are being loaded, the page scrolls to the bottom "where they are" and refuse to scroll up til they finish loading. how can I stop scrolling to the bottom?

```
        <iframe id="upload_target0" name="upload_target0" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
        <iframe id="upload_target1" name="upload_target1" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
        <iframe id="upload_target2" name="upload_target2" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
        <iframe id="upload_target3" name="upload_target3" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
        <iframe id="upload_target4" name="upload_target4" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
        <iframe id="upload_target5" name="upload_target5" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
        <iframe id="upload_target6" name="upload_target6" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

`#` resolves to the current URL. Specify an empty string, nothing, or `about:blank`.
Also, instead of repeating `width:0;height:0;border:0;`, use `display:none;` in a separate CSS rule.

```
<iframe id="upload_target0" name="upload_target0" src="about:blank" class="upload_target"></iframe>

.upload_target {display:none;}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. that solved the issue. I will accept your answer once I'm allowed :)